# Regex to accept number between 0 and 20 and followed by an optional decmiall numbers

Tags: regex

I'am trying to get regex which can validate accepted numbers between 0 to 20 and these numbers can followed by an optional decmial point, followed by one or two digits. and not allow special characters
it should be accept :

```
1 true
2 true
2.5 true
.
.
15,25 true
16.369 false
16++++ false
16,32-+* false
20 true
```

I tried this but it accept 16,25++++

```
 var regex = /^(?:1?\d(?:\.\d{1,2})?|20(?:\.0?0?)?)$/
```

Comment: Does that include 0 as well? Or does it start at 1 till 20.00 inclusive?

Comment: yes it's not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
^(?:(?:\d|1[0-9])(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?|20(?:[,.]0{1,2})?)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:\d|1[0-9])` Match 0-9 or 10 - 19
  - `(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?` Match optional part to match a decimal and 1-2 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `20(?:[,.]0{1,2})?` Match 20 with an optional part to match a decimal and 1-2 zeroes
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/36JVkg/1)

Comment: OP asked for "optional decmial point, followed by one or two digits", not "zeroes". So, it should be `20(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?`.

Comment: @user1016274 validate accepted numbers between 0 to 20 and that would also match 20.99 which is larger than 20. Also if you look at OP's pattern you see `20(?:\.0?0?)?` which indicates that 20 with optional zeroes was meant as well.